# Is it possible to update a mongo document as well as insert a embeded document in the same document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Supposed this is a document inserted in mongo db.  I want to add another document in the Attachment and also update the last_update_time in single query.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("64d0a5cdc9311cad167f55d5"),
"Title" : "Main",
"last_update_time" : epoch_time,
"Attachment" : [
        {
                "key" : "1111.jpg",
                "file_name" : "Mongodb.jpg",
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need are two update operators in the change argument to updateOne function.

1. $set for last_update_time.
2. $push to add item to the Attachment array.

   ```
   db.collection.updateOne(
      {"_id" : ObjectId("64d0a5cdc9311cad167f55d5")},
      { 
         $set:{last_update_time: new Date()}, 
         $push: { Attachment: { "key" : "2222.jpg", "file_name" : "Mongodb.jpg" } } 
      }
   )
   ```